# State is overriding with last updated value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-state

I have below function where i am updating the array that is stored in state as array and i have 9 tables and for each table i am calling this function to check the status and if it is true then i will be storing that in array.

```
const [projectSpaceTypeWarning, setProjectSpaceTypeWarning] = useState([]);

const handleWarning = (librarySourceTableWarning, status) => {
let spaceTypeWarningCount = [...projectSpaceTypeWarning];
if (status) {
  spaceTypeWarningCount.push(librarySourceTableWarning);
} else {
  spaceTypeWarningCount = spaceTypeWarningCount.filter(
    item => item !== librarySourceTableWarning
  );
 }
setProjectSpaceTypeWarning(spaceTypeWarningCount);
};
```

and i am setting another variable based in this state like as below

```
 if (projectSpaceTypeWarning.length) {
  values.spaceType.isInWarningState = true;
}
```

My issue here is i am updating this state with one table that is giving `status` as true and it is setting the state accordingly and that is fine. I have remaining tables those are all sending the status as false and setting the status accordingly. Somehow the `false` status is overriding `true` status inside the state array.

Could any one please let me know any suggestions or any ideas how i can overcome this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: handleWarning fun looks ok ... maybe prob is something to do with direct mutation(?) ... can u show more code around `values.space` ... like how/where `values` is defined etc..

Comment: even if i have one table that is sending status as true this will be zero `projectSpaceTypeWarning.length`

Comment: When are the other tables looking at `projectSpaceTypeWarning.length`? If it is any time during the *same* render cycle that `handleWarning` is invoked then OFC it will still be referencing the *current* state value. React updates are asynchronous and batched process between render/commit phases.

Comment: Not enough code to show what the problem is but it could be that projectSpaceTypeWarning is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) or your filter isn't working if you are comparing objects (`{} !== {}`). If you can't solve the problem then can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (not a 5 page code dump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using below code

```
    const handleWarning = (librarySourceTableWarning, status) => {
    let spaceTypeWarningCount = projectSpaceTypeWarning; // changes at here
    if (status) {
      spaceTypeWarningCount.push(librarySourceTableWarning);
    } else {
      spaceTypeWarningCount = spaceTypeWarningCount.filter(
        item => item !== librarySourceTableWarning
      );
    }
    setProjectSpaceTypeWarning(spaceTypeWarningCount);
   };
```